# Do not add same entry onto xml via powershell command

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML file which requires entries under the runtime node (highlighted in red):

[image: XMLfile]

I am able to achive this via the following PowerShell script

```bsh
$appFrameContainerAppConfig = 'D:\H.Infrastructure.AppFrame.Container.exe.config'
$doc = (Get-Content $appFrameContainerAppConfig) -as [Xml] 

$root = $doc.get_DocumentElement()

$newDependentAssembly = $doc.CreateElement("dependentAssembly")

$newAssemblyIdentity = $doc.CreateElement("assemblyIdentity")
$newAssemblyIdentity.SetAttribute("name","EntityFramework")
$newAssemblyIdentity.SetAttribute("publicKeyToken","b77a5c561934e089")
$newAssemblyIdentity.SetAttribute("culture","neutral")
$newDependentAssembly.AppendChild($newAssemblyIdentity)

$newCodeBase = $doc.CreateElement("codeBase")
$newCodeBase.SetAttribute("version","6.0.0.0")
$newCodeBase.SetAttribute("href","EntityFramework_6.1.3/EntityFramework.dll")
$newDependentAssembly.AppendChild($newCodeBase)

$root.runtime.assemblyBinding.AppendChild($newDependentAssembly)

$newDependentAssembly = $doc.CreateElement("dependentAssembly")

$newAssemblyIdentity = $doc.CreateElement("assemblyIdentity")
$newAssemblyIdentity.SetAttribute("name","EntityFramework.SqlServer")
$newAssemblyIdentity.SetAttribute("publicKeyToken","b77a5c561934e089")
$newAssemblyIdentity.SetAttribute("culture","neutral")
$newDependentAssembly.AppendChild($newAssemblyIdentity)

$newCodeBase = $doc.CreateElement("codeBase")
$newCodeBase.SetAttribute("version","6.0.0.0")
$newCodeBase.SetAttribute("href","EntityFramework_6.1.3/EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll")
$newDependentAssembly.AppendChild($newCodeBase)

$root.runtime.assemblyBinding.AppendChild($newDependentAssembly)

$newDependentAssembly = $doc.CreateElement("dependentAssembly")

$newAssemblyIdentity = $doc.CreateElement("assemblyIdentity")
$newAssemblyIdentity.SetAttribute("name","System.Data.SQLite")
$newAssemblyIdentity.SetAttribute("publicKeyToken","db937bc2d44ff139")
$newAssemblyIdentity.SetAttribute("culture","neutral")
$newDependentAssembly.AppendChild($newAssemblyIdentity)

$newCodeBase = $doc.CreateElement("codeBase")
$newCodeBase.SetAttribute("version","1.0.98.0")
$newCodeBase.SetAttribute("href","SQLite_1.0.98.1/System.Data.SQLite.dll")
$newDependentAssembly.AppendChild($newCodeBase)

$root.runtime.assemblyBinding.AppendChild($newDependentAssembly)

$newDependentAssembly = $doc.CreateElement("dependentAssembly")

$newAssemblyIdentity = $doc.CreateElement("assemblyIdentity")
$newAssemblyIdentity.SetAttribute("name","System.Data.SQLite.EF6")
$newAssemblyIdentity.SetAttribute("publicKeyToken","db937bc2d44ff139")
$newAssemblyIdentity.SetAttribute("culture","neutral")
$newDependentAssembly.AppendChild($newAssemblyIdentity)

$newCodeBase = $doc.CreateElement("codeBase")
$newCodeBase.SetAttribute("version","1.0.98.0")
$newCodeBase.SetAttribute("href","SQLite_1.0.98.1/System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll")
$newDependentAssembly.AppendChild($newCodeBase)

$root.runtime.assemblyBinding.AppendChild($newDependentAssembly)

$newDependentAssembly = $doc.CreateElement("dependentAssembly")

$newAssemblyIdentity = $doc.CreateElement("assemblyIdentity")
$newAssemblyIdentity.SetAttribute("name","System.Data.SQLite.Linq")
$newAssemblyIdentity.SetAttribute("publicKeyToken","db937bc2d44ff139")
$newAssemblyIdentity.SetAttribute("culture","neutral")
$newDependentAssembly.AppendChild($newAssemblyIdentity)

$newCodeBase = $doc.CreateElement("codeBase")
$newCodeBase.SetAttribute("version","1.0.98.0")
$newCodeBase.SetAttribute("href","SQLite_1.0.98.1/System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll")
$newDependentAssembly.AppendChild($newCodeBase)

$root.runtime.assemblyBinding.AppendChild($newDependentAssembly)
Write-Output $root.runtime.assemblyBinding.dependentAssembly
$doc.Save($appFrameContainerAppConfig)
```

I require a condition which evaluates if the entries highlighted in red are present in XML if so avoid adding the same.

```bsh
if($root.SelectNodes('//configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity[@name="EntityFramework"]')) {
} else {
}
```

The condition I use here does not seem to work. It does not come inside if or else condition. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `<runtime>` node already contains entries, e.g. like this:

```
if ($root.SelectNodes('//runtime/dependentAssembly').Count -eq 0) {
  ...
}
```

Adjust the [XPath expression](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/expressions.html) if you need more fine-grained checks.

**Edit:** Apparently your XML data uses namespaces, so you need a namespace manager for selecting nodes with a namespace:

```
$nsm = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($doc.NameTable)
$nsm.AddNamespace('ns', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1')
if ($doc.SelectNodes('//ns:assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity[@name="EntityFramework"]', $nsm).Count -eq 0) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work and i still end up creating duplicate entries. In fact it doesnot come into the if loop at all

Comment: "Doesn't work" is an insufficient problem description. Please edit your quesiton and provide evidence.

Comment: I meant  the if loop does not get executed i wrote some write output withing if loop which does not get executed

Comment: To be precise I would like to check if assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" and code base version exists. I am unable to extract the same using if loop

Comment: `if` statements are not loops. And your node creation code is supposed to go inside the `if` block. I thought that was obvious. As for defining a more fine-grained check: I already linked relevant documentation in my answer. I suggest you start reading it.

Comment: Could you please be more clear, I am new to this. If is a loop in case the condition fails i suppose it gets into else condition loop. That fine grain check has syntax which i did try but failed to get the required result.

Comment: `if` statements are [conditionals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_%28computer_programming%29), not [loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_%28computing%29). As for the check: what exactly did you try? I'm not sitting in front of your computer, and I don't enjoy playing guessing games.

Comment: Sir in case u do not have patience please stop answering here rather than being rude, I have pasted my entire code here. In case you can help please do so it else please stop answering here. The if loop you provided did not help me.

Comment: Check was if ($root.SelectNodes("//runtime/dependentAssembly/assemblybinding").Count > 0)

Comment: There is no node `assemblybinding` in your XML sample. Try `//runtime/dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity[@name="EntityFramework"]` for selecting nodes whose `name` attribute has the value "EntityFramework". Beware that XPath is case-sensitive. And `>` is a [redirection operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) in PowerShell, not a [comparison operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx). For further help show the XML structure to which you want to add your XML snippet.

Comment: Ok this is the xml in which I need to add the entityframework and sqlite references                                                                                                            <configuration>

Comment: Please edit your question. It's probably too long for a comment, and it would be unreadable in a comment anyway.

Comment: Hi Ansgar is there anyway to attach the code or probably Can I message you my code, I tried editing here but looks like I did not format the code properly and it mentions format the code.

Comment: For formatting help see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). You should be able to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39076371/edit) regardless, though.

Comment: I have edited[I ve attached an image and code snippet]. Please let me know if it gives you a clear picture of the issue I am facing, Thanks for your support on this.

Comment: See updated answer. Please do not withold essential information like the fact that your XML has namespaces in the future.